# Angular variable DeployURL

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, lazy-loading

We are trying to include lazy loading in our angular application but we ran into an issue. The chunks that are generated by the cli are on another domain than the one the angular project is trying find it.

Now with the deployUrl we can configure it to look in the correct place but the only issue is that we need to redefine it for different environments  **without rebuilding the entire application**. Does anyone have an idea of how this can be solved ?

Comment: maybe just do a search and replace over your dist folder to change the 'old' deployUrl in a new?

In my project deployUrl didn't fit my need. I use the baseHref. In this way I could put al my assets in an other folder

Answer (score 0):

You can have a file called `config.js` in your `assets` folder where you can define the url and store it in a global variable
like this.

config.js

```
deployUrl = "http://someurl.com";
```

Now you need to include this file in `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"scripts": [
    "assets/config.js",
    ...
]
```

You can easily use `deployUrl` in any `ts` file just remember to declare `deployUrl` :

```
declare var deployUrl;
```

Now you can just change the value of `deployUrl` variable and on saving the file changes will be immediately reflected, no build needed.

NOTE: This is not the proper `angular` way but does the job without rebuilding entire app

Comment: the op asked about changing the deploy-url (where the chunks are served from) and not reading run-time configuration from external file